# Navigation Bar On The Same Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I'm sure that my problem is simple, but I have poor experience on designing in general.

I'm working on a simple PHP website project, and I have a navigation bar and want when click on one of the bars don't go to another page, rather just change a specified panel content according what the clicked button.

I think this could be done by using ajax and div but I think also there is a convenient and clear way to do that professionally.

Just ignore the unrelated lines or code, assuming that I want when click on one of the tab write a message of that tab or button without reloading.

My html file:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>

    <html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
        <head>
            <title>Main view</title>
            <link href="MainAdminStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <script src="myjavascript.js"></script>
        </head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <body>
            <img src="image/RightImage.jpg" style="width:100%; height: 200"/>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">bla</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">bla1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">bla2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.html">bla3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

MainAdminStyle.css

```
#menu {
    width: 800px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    background-color: #8AD9FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#menu li { 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 20px; 
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00F;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #F90;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Ok, where is your code?

Comment: Is AJAX and div not convenient and clear or professional?

Comment: I said I don't have good experience on designing even front-end in general, I use ajax on simple examples but not with div.

Comment: Can you perhaps show us the JavaScript that you are using? We want to help, but unless we know what the problem is,we won't be able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadPage(url, into)
            {
                into = document.getElementById(into);
                into.innerHTML = 'Loading...';

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', url, true);

                xhr.onload = function()
                { into.innerHTML = xhr.response; }

                xhr.send(null);
            }

            window.onload = function()
            {
                var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
                var list = [].slice.call(menu.getElementsByTagName('a'));

                list.forEach(function(link)
                {
                    link.onclick = function()
                    {
                        loadPage(this.href, 'content');
                        return false;
                    };
                });
            };
        </script>
        <style>
            .debug
            { border:1px solid #BADA55; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu" class="debug">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">bla</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html">bla1</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">bla2</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.html">bla3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="debug">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

just copy & paste into a new file.html.
edit it as you want ;)

Comment: Awesome.
Thanks @Charl , the front-end issue needs a lot of time to achieve even a simple thing.